# Firestore on smapshot proper clean-up with async function in useeffect hook

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, react-hooks

I have a Firebase Chat application.

In order to decrease the initial load of Javascript, I am defining a function to get Firestore when I initialize the app, but I will call it only later. It looks like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

export const firebaseApp = initializeApp({ ... });

export const getFirestoreDatabase = async () => {
  const { getFirestore } = await import('firebase/firestore');
  return getFirestore(firebaseApp);
};
```

In another file, I am using a useEffect hook to set an "onSnapshot" hook to get messages when they are incoming. I have to use useEffect since the ID of the discussion changes.

It looks like this:

```
import { collection, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
...
useEffect(() => {
    async function getConv() {
      const DB = await getFirestoreDatabase()
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(DB, 'chat'), (d) => { ... });
      return () => unsubscribe()
    }
    getConv()
  }, [chatId]);
```

My question is, how do I properly cleanup the onSnapshot using `unsubscribe`? When there is no async function involved, it is easy, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(DB, 'chat'), (d) => { ... });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [chatId]);
```

But when there is async involved, I do not know how to do it.

Disclaimers:

- I am quite new to React, sorry if I am doing smth stupid.
- What is inside the onSnapshot is slightly different, but it should not have an impact on how unsibscribe should be used